# CKEditor - text in image preview dialog in English

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor on my site and I want to change text in the Image->Properties->Preview to English.

I want to change this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat consequat diam. Maecenas metus. Vivamus diam purus, cursus a, commodo non, facilisis vitae, nulla. Aenean dictum lacinia tortor. Nunc iaculis, nibh non iaculis aliquam, orci felis euismod neque, sed ornare massa mauris sed velit. Nulla pretium mi et risus. Fusce mi pede, tempor id, cursus ac, ullamcorper nec, enim. Sed tortor. Curabitur molestie. Duis velit augue, condimentum at, ultrices a, luctus ut, orci. Donec pellentesque egestas eros. Integer cursus, augue in cursus faucibus, eros pede bibendum sem, in tempus tellus justo quis ligula. Etiam eget tortor. Vestibulum rutrum, est ut placerat elementum, lectus nisl aliquam velit, tempor aliquam eros nunc nonummy metus. In eros metus, gravida a, gravida sed, lobortis id, turpis. Ut ultrices, ipsum at venenatis fringilla, sem nulla lacinia tellus, eget aliquet turpis mauris non enim. Nam turpis. Suspendisse lacinia. Curabitur ac tortor ut ipsum egestas elementum. Nunc imperdiet gravida mauris.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to *insert real text instead of placeholder text?* You know that's [not a real language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum), right?

Comment: That's [filler text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text). It's not in any real language *by design*. It's just there so that the result of changing the image alignment is visible. Why would you want to have real text there?

Comment: :) I thought it was a real language, I want to have a real text, to avoid confusion. the dummy text look like spanish language.

Comment: Lorem Ipsum looks like Latin but has no real meaning, quite a few people know it as the standard placeholder text though :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your response,it's very informative.....

Comment: http://lipsum.com/: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set this text using the [config.image_previewText](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-image_previewText) option.

E.g.

```
config.image_previewText = 'In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is' +
    'placeholder text (filler text) commonly used to demonstrate the graphic' +
    'elements of a document or visual presentation';
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to change in  **path\ckeditor\plugins\image\dialogs** and edit file **image.js**  ,you can ctrl+f and search "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer"